# If url param then return a view else go to the controller in Laravel route

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a SearchController that sets a session variable and sends the user to the staff.resultList view.  There is a link that switches views from a list to a grid view.  I am trying to add a conditional statement that facilitates that switch. In my route file I have :

```
Route::get('home/memberhome/search', function(){
    if(isset($_GET['resultView']) && Session::has('lastSearch')){
        if($_GET['resultView'] == 'grid'){
            return view('staff.resultsGrid');
        } else {
            return view('staff.resultList');
        }
    } else {
        'SearchController@getAvailablity';
    }
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I am not sure of the right syntax to get this to run the controller if the condition is not meant and to just display the views if the conditions are met.

Can I make this work or is there a different approach I should be using?

**Route File**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
 */

use App\Http\Controllers;
// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use Mail;
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('home/memberhome');
});


Route::get('/sso/{accessCode}', 'SsoController@ssoLogin');
Route::get('/ssofailure', 'SsoController@ssoFail');
// Route::get('/optimum/{searchString?}', 'OptimumController@getAutoComplete($searchString=""');

Route::get('home/memberhome/search', function(){
    if(isset($_GET['resultView']) && Session::has('lastSearch')){
        if($_GET['resultView'] == 'grid'){
            return view('staff.resultsGrid');
        } else {
            return view('staff.resultList');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->action('SearchController@getAvailablity');
    }
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:super_admin admin']], function () {
    // REPORTS ROUTES
    Route::get('dashboard/reports', 'ReportController@index');
    Route::get('dashboard/reports/filter', 'ReportController@filterReports');
    Route::get('dashboard/reports/export/{id}', 'ReportController@export');
    Route::get('dashboard/reports/{id}/bookings', 'ReportController@reports');
    Route::get('dashboard/reports/{id}/bookings/search', 'ReportController@searchBookings');
    Route::get('dashboard/client/search', 'ClientController@search');
    Route::get('dashboard/clients/create', 'ClientController@create');
    Route::post('dashboard/clients/store', 'ClientController@store');


    // INVOICE ROUTES
    Route::get('dashboard/invoices', 'InvoiceController@index');
    Route::post('dashboard/invoices', 'InvoiceController@store');
    Route::get('dashboard/invoices/edit/{id}', 'InvoiceController@edit');
    Route::post('dashboard/invoices/edit/{id}', 'InvoiceController@updateBooking');
    Route::get('dashboard/invoices/remove/{id}', 'InvoiceController@removeBooking');
    Route::get('dashboard/invoice/export/{id}', 'InvoiceController@export');
    Route::post('dashboard/invoices/{id}/paid', 'InvoiceController@markPaid');
    Route::get('dashboard/invoices/{id}', 'InvoiceController@show');

});
```

Comment: You can use `redirect()->action('SearchController@getAvailablity');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the user to another controller's action like this:

```
return redirect()->action('SearchController@getAvailablity');
```

So it would be something like this:

```
Route::get('home/memberhome/search', function(){
    if(isset($_GET['resultView']) && Session::has('lastSearch')){
        if($_GET['resultView'] == 'grid'){
            return view('staff.resultsGrid');
        } else {
            return view('staff.resultList');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->action('SearchController@getAvailablity');
    }
});
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

### Update

If your controller's method is not registered in any routes, you can access it like this:

```
return app(App\Http\Controllers\SearchController::class)->getAvailablity();
```

So it would be something like this:

```
Route::get('home/memberhome/search', function(){
    if(isset($_GET['resultView']) && Session::has('lastSearch')){
        if($_GET['resultView'] == 'grid'){
            return view('staff.resultsGrid');
        } else {
            return view('staff.resultList');
        }
    } else {
        return app(App\Http\Controllers\SearchController::class)->getAvailablity();
    }
});
```

Comment: This results in : `Action App\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getAvailablity not defined.` Which I know is not the case since if I change the route file to `Route::get('home/memberhome/search', 'SearchController@getAvailablity');` it does hit the controller.  Sorry I am very new to this framework

Comment: @Lance Can you update your question with your route file?

Comment: @Lance I've moved your routes into your question instead of my answer. I do not see any routes with the `SearchController@getAvailablity`?

Comment: Sorry for putting them in the wrong place :-(  Thank you for your help!!